# What is the best place to put onEnter, onExit callback functionality?

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am creating my first project that uses ui-router.

My project has about 10 views, each with their own controller and state. I am trying to modularise/encapsulate/decouple as best as possible but I am having trouble working out where to put the onExit and onEnter state callbacks.

The first option is to put it in app.js which is currently defining all of my states, however I feel that this would not be a good place as it could cause this file to blow up and become hard to read as more states are introduced and the logic gets more complex.

The second option I looked into was to put it into a controller (I have one for each state), however from researching it doesn't seem to be best practice to do this.

The third option is to create a service that is resolved, however with this option I would end up with either a giant service full of state change functions for each of the states (not decoupled) or an additional service per state which would contain the state change functionality, and I worry that would increase project complexity.

What is the standard way to achieve this?

Are there any other options that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Our strategy for this has been to disregard the onEnter and onExit on the state object, because as you are discovering, they feel like they are in the wrong place in terms of separation of concerns (app.js).

For onEnter: we handle setup in an `activate()` function in each controller, which we manually execute inside the controller.  This happens to also match the callback that will get executed in Angular 2.0, which was not an accident ;).

```
function activate() {
    // your setup code here
}

// execute it.  this line can be removed in Angular 2.0
activate();
```

For onExit: We rarely need an exit callback, but when we do, we listen for the $scope $destroy event.

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    if (timer) {
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
    }
});
```